# PHP preg_match template array as a second argument not working

Tags: php, templates, preg-replace

I found this neat code from: https://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3444822.htm

First example seems to work well:

```
$firstname = "Eric";
$lastname = "Johnsson";
echo preg_replace("/\{([^\{]{1,100}?)\}/e", "$$1", "{lastname}, {firstname}");
```

But when I try to use second array version, it gives me index and other errors what ever combinations I try:

```
$values = array('firstname'=>'Eric', 'lastname'=>'Johnsson');
echo preg_replace("/\{([^\{]{1,100}?)\}/e", "$values[$1]", "{lastname}, {firstname}");
```

In PHP 5.5x it "should" work. PHP 7.x -> needs to have second argument a function, not accepting -e argument on regex.

Does anyone know working solution to second version? I rather not use export function to extract variables to the working scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `preg_replace_callback` as in the code below:

```
$values = array('firstname'=>'Eric', 'lastname'=>'Johnsson');
echo preg_replace_callback("/{([^{}]*)}/", function($m) use ($values) {
    return !empty($values[$m[1]]) ? $values[$m[1]] : $m[0];
}, "{lastname}, {firstname} {somestring}");
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/R1HCrK)

Note that to pass the `$values` to the anonymous callback function, you need to pass it within `use` argument. With `!empty($values[$m[1]])` you can check if your array contains the necessary key-value, and if yes, replace with it, and if not, just restore the match with the current match value, `$m[0]`.

Note you do not need to escape `{` and `}` in this pattern, and you may just use `{([^{}]*)}` to match any number of chars other than `{` and `}` between `{` and `}`. If you are only interested in the substrings containing word chars, a `{(\w+)}` pattern could be more suitable.

Comment: Answer delivers more than asked, but I will accept it anyway :-) (gladly)